# Hide QSplitter child but keep the position of the handle

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QSplitter and two child widgets in it. Let's say p_widget_1 and p_widget_2. p_widget_1 is allowed to be closed, it has a Close button and when Close is clicked I call p_widget_1->hide(). QSplitter [doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplitter.html)  says:

> When you hide() a child, its space will be distributed among the other children. It will be reinstated when you show() it again.

But I want the QSplitter's handle to keep its position as I have a requirement that p_widget_2 should have fixed size.

How do I achieve it? My current approach is calling p_splitter->setSizes() when necessary but it doesn't always work in all my cases.

I am on Windows, QT is 5.4.1, Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try on a particular QWidget (like your QSplitter) but this is what I do when I want to restore the geometry of a window after it is closed:

- Before the child is hidden, save the QByteArray retrieved with the
  following function (on your QSplitter)

  QByteArray QWidget::saveGeometry() const
- After the child is displayed again, call the following method with
  the QByteArray you just stored

  bool QWidget::restoreGeometry(const QByteArray & geometry)

Documentation [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#restoreGeometry).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this solve your problem or not. Try 'saveSate' method to save state of QSplitter and restore it by 'restoreState' method.